# Swagger special character in query

Tags: node.js, swagger

Swagger is currently appending special characters to my query, as stated in this document https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/, adding **allowReserved: true** should fix the issue, but I have tried that and the special characters are still appended.
[image]

**Europe%2FAndorra** should be **Europe/Andorra**

How can this issue be resolved? a possible workaround will also be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Please post your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file. 2) What tool do you use to send requests - Swagger UI or something else?

Comment: yeah, I used Swagger UI, below is the JSON sample
`
  "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "timezone",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "allowReserved": true
            "schema": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "Asia/Dubai"
            }
          }
        ]
`